# IIS throws NullReferenceException after changing virtual directory

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

IIS will sometimes throw a `NullReferenceException` from `System.Web.HttpApplication.GetNotificationContextProperties` immediately after we deploy a new build of our MVC application. The build steps we run are:

1. Copy new binaries to new directory on server
2. Point IIS at the new virtual directory

Immediately after this, loading the page throws an error.

The full exception message is:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>
> System.Web.HttpApplication.GetNotificationContextProperties(Boolean& isReentry, Int32& eventCount) +116
>
> System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
>   +197 
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb) +89
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +189

Hitting the server with an IISReset clears out the error and the site functions as normal.

Most solutions I've found so far mention that the issue occurs when wiring up event handlers in the Application_Start method, but we have no code that does that. Does anybody have any insight on how we might be able to fix this without running an IISReset on every deployment?

Comment: Don't call GetNotificationContextProperties immediately on startup?  Catch the exception and retry?  Catch, wait, and retry?

Comment: Did you create a new app pool for the new application and/or stop the old app pool servicing the old application?

Comment: @RossBush we are not starting up a new app pool, they persist across deploys. It was my impression that re-pointing the virtual directory would recycle the app pool anyway.

Comment: @topher - That very well may be. I would be curious to find out if the app pool servicing the endpoint is immediately recycled after pointing to the new location. Instead of a full IIS Reset, I wonder if  you could  just manually recycle the app pool immediately after pointing to a new location  and then see if you can reproduce? Also, why don't you just reuse the old application folder?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you not using [Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) to publish your site?